# How to change the hive job name instead of displaying query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have tried to set custom job name by using the property hive.query.string but it's not working.

I also tried with setting mapreduce.job.name it does changed the job name but am losing stage number info.

```
1489970032795_1709  COOKIE_TO_TID_13MAR
```

I would like to see some thing like this

```
1489970032795_1709  COOKIE_TO_TID_13MAR(Stage-1)
```

I see the similar question in following link but it didn't work for as I tried hive.query.string

[How do I control a hive job name but keep the stage info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036371/how-do-i-control-a-hive-job-name-but-keep-the-stage-info)

Cloudera     : CDH 5.4.11
Hive version : 1.1.0