# How to set mapreduce job name for hive query child jobs?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hive-query

our hive query creates 9 map-reduce jobs and 17 stages(when I ran EXPLAIN command, output showed 17 STAGES and STAGE DEPENDENCIES). 
Every child job has the same `mapreduce.job.name`

To distinguish these child jobs, is there any way I can set the `mapreduce.job.name` inside the hive query so that for each job, I can see the stage of the job.
existing job name for all 9 child jobs:

```
Job.Name : hive_query_map_reduce_job
```

Is there a way I can get the job names in job tracker as

```
Job.Name : hive_query_map_reduce_job_stage_1
Job.Name : hive_query_map_reduce_job_stage_2
Job.Name : hive_query_map_reduce_job_stage_3
...
```

I refered [How do I control a hive job name but keep the stage info?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19036371/5963014) but it did not work as expected.
I tried setting `mapreduce.job.name` inside the query at multiple places with different values but all the child jobs are taking the last value I assigned.
Say my query file is hiveQuery.q

**hiveQuery.q**

set hiveconf:mapreduce.job.name="unique name 1".
...
--some query statements
...
set hiveconf:mapreduce.job.name="unique name 2".
...
--some query statements
...
set hiveconf:mapreduce.job.name="unique name 3".

For the above query, All the 9 mapreduce jobs took `"unique name 3"` as the job name.
I also tried `hive.query.name` and `hive.query.string` but those didn't help.
Is this possible? Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19715386/2202107